# PostgreSQL recovery.conf archive_cleanup_command parameter

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-replication

I have a setup of PostgreSQL 9.6 under windows and a hot stand by under windows too.

In the recovery.conf file I've setted up 
archive_cleanup_command = '"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\pg_archivecleanup.exe" "C:\Replication\ARCHIVELOG\" "%r"'

Problem is that %r is not getting replaced when this command is called!
Has anyone had this problem before??

Comment: What are you seeing which indicates that that is the problem?

Comment: Backwhacks in archive_cleanup_command need to be doubled.